# Too many outputs error in MATLAB 2013a

Tags: matlab

I am suffering an error whose identifier is 'MATLAB:TooManyOutputs' in MATLAB 2013a when executing a code that didn't fail in MATLAB 2012b.

The line which produces this error is

```
handles.Project = project;
```

where `project` is a struct (size 1x1) and `handles` is a struct with the handles of the GUI that I have created. `Project` is a field of the struct `handles` which doesn't exist prior to the above line.

What seems very strange to me is that if I put a breakpoint in the line before that which I have shown, I comment it and, when the execution is paused due to that breakpoint, I write manually in the MATLAB command line `handles.Project = project;` there is no error.

Where may the error be? What's wrong?

Thank you.

EDIT: There is another unexplainable issue. I have found out that this line doesn't crash my program in MATLAB 2013a for UNIX, but it does in MATLAB 2013a for Windows.

EDIT2: I have discovered there is a new function in MATLAB 2013a for Windows which is called `project`, so I guess MATLAB thinks I am calling it instead of the variable I really want. The problem is I can't change the name of my variable (because it is stored in a MAT-file which is created by another program whose code I don't have access to). So, is there any way to say: "MATLAB, I want you to use this variable rather than your new function"?

Comment: Could you set a breakpoint to that line and type in `which project` when it stops there? What is the output? There must be something else named project which is covering the visibility of the struct.

Comment: @Daniel `which project` returns: `project is a variable.` If I write `project` in the MATLAB command line it shows it is a struct with two fields, which is correct.

Comment: @Daniel You're right. Look at my EDIT2 comment, please.

Comment: show the part of the code where you load the data from the MAT-file

Comment: @Amro It's as simple as `load([directory_name filename]);`, where the text between brackets determines the path of the MAT-file.

Comment: you could load the data as `D = load([..])` then access the individual variables contained inside the MAT-file as: `D.project` (no ambiguity there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the [`load` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) with an output argument, the contents of the MAT-file will be returned as a structure, one field per variable. This way you avoid polluting the workspace especially if you have many variables stored in the MAT-file, and avoid possible name clashes.

```
D = load('some_file.mat');
handles.Project = D.project;
```

Comment: The only detail I haven't understood yet is why MATLAB wasn't able to identify `project` as a variable when it was executing my program, but **it did** when I manually wrote `handles.Project = project` in the command line.

Comment: that's a good question. If I have access to your code I might be able to answer you (it's difficult to debug something with seeing the code and being able to interact with it)... I guess it has to do with the fact that the same name was used as both a function call and a variable inside the same scope, but I can't tell for sure. That might explain why you see a different behavior between the command line and the executing function.

Comment: truth is I never liked the way `load` function works by default (called with no output argument), it introduces variables in the current workspace out of thin air.. This makes the code hard to read, especially when called inside functions. Whereas using the struct syntax makes it clear where the variables are coming from.